# Bootstrap: Dropdown main menu issue

Tags: menu, dropdown

I need help with this menu http://soulskydesign.com/RALE%20Engineering/Predlog_dizajna_001/
When I press PRODUCTS on this main menu I get open also sub-menu.
What I need to change in code so when I press PRODUCTS I don't get open sub-menu?

Comment: post your code here (html)

Comment: I found the solution. 
I put this in my CSS file

/ custom dropdown menu start / 
li.dropdown-submenu ul.dropdown-menu {  
    display:none !important;  <br>
}
li.dropdown-submenu.open ul.dropdown-menu {   
    display:block !important;   
}
/ custom dropdown menu ends /

Comment: Why don't you put your working code in an answer to your question to help the next person who has a similar problem.  You are allowed to answer your own question.  Remember to indent 4 spaces for each line so that it will show up as code in the answer